# Stop automatic sorting of HTML options in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have two HTML select boxes. I am moving options from one box to the other, box "from[]" and box "to[], respectively. The problem I have is that, the "to[]" box sorts my options alphabetically as they are added. I want each option to be appended to the box and have no sorting at all.

I have done a lot of reading on this and it seems like the "to[]" box should keep the order of the options as they are added but it does not.

I left my commented out code in my Javascript just you can see what I have tried. I'll remove it if it is making everything too messy.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<select name="from[]" id="fabricBox" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%">

<select name="to[]" id="fabricBox_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple" required></select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#fabricBox').dblclick (function(){
                $value = $('#fabricBox option:selected').val();
                $('#fabricBox_to').append($value); 

// $('#fabricBox_to').val() = $value 

// $text = $('#fabricBox option:selected').text();

// $("#fabricBox_to").append($('<option></option>').attr("value",$value).text($text));
```

Comment: A working `fiddle` example would be useful.

Comment: Options should be shown in the order in which they are present in the html.  If that's not happening, there may be some sort of undesireable browser "autoordering".  Please also post browser being used and version.

Comment: There's nothing jumping out at me that would cause this based on the code you posted. Can you create a JSFiddle or CodePen to demonstrate the problem? That would be very helpful.

Comment: I'll make a fiddle right now. Also, I am using the newest version of Chrome.

Comment: I'm betting you have some other component you're loading (to change the appearance or behaviour of the select box for instance) which is doing the reordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in four steps:

1) You can **map** all selected options and return them as a **delimited string** `(,)`

2) Now **split** the string into an **array**.

3) **Remove** items that are moved from the **From** select element to the **To** one.

4) Finally **loop through the array** appending the options to the second select element.

---

### Multi Select Example below

```js
//move items from fabricBox to fabricBox_to
$("#move").on("click", function(){
  MoveToandFrom("#fabricBox", "#fabricBox_to");
});

//You can even move the options back if you need to
$("#moveBack").on("click", function(){
  MoveToandFrom("#fabricBox_to", "#fabricBox");
});

//reusable function that moves selected indexes back and forth
function MoveToandFrom(fromSelectElement, toSelectElement)
{
  //get list of selected options as delimited string
  var selected = $(fromSelectElement + " option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get().join(", ");
  
  //if no option is selected in either select box
  if( $.contains(selected, "") ){
    alert("You have to select an option!");
    return false;
  }
  
  //split the selected options into an array 
  var stringArray = selected.split(',');
   
  //remove selected items from selected select box to second select box
  $(fromSelectElement + " option:selected").remove();
   
  //loop through array and append the selected items to Fabric_to select box
  $.each( stringArray, function( key, value ) {
      $(toSelectElement).append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label for="fabricBox">From</label>
  <select name="from[]" id="fabricBox" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%">
    <option>Fabric 1</option>
    <option>Fabric 2</option>
    <option>Fabric 3</option>
    <option>Fabric 4</option>
    <option>Fabric 5</option>
    <option>Fabric 6</option>
  </select>
  <button id="move">Move Selected</button>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <label for="fabricBox_to">To</label>
  <select name="to[]" id="fabricBox_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%" required>
  </select>
  <button id="moveBack">Move Selected back</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That works! I'll need to change the data a bit on my end but it accomplishes the task at hand. Thanks!

Comment: @EvanLalo No problem. This was a pretty fun question.

Answer (score 0):

I could not test it, but something like this should work:

```
$("#fabricBox_to option:last").append('<option>' + $value + '</option>');
```